# Nette Form - set default value on text (type date) in FormFactory

Tags: php, forms, date, nette

I have no idea how to set, or if it is even possible to set default value on text (type date).

Here is my FormFactory:

```
$form->addText('category_priority', 'Prioritizovať do')
        ->setHtmlType('date')
        ->setDefaultValue( $date )   // select from db in format Y-m-d ('2020-12-01')
        ->setHtmlAttribute('class', 'add');
```

I tried changing formats, because meaby it wont take the original one with this, but no luck:

```
use Nette\Utils\DateTime;
$original = DateTime::from($priority);
$priority  = $original->format('d. m. Y');
```

Did somebody encountered same problem?

Comment: The main problem is the format. Html type date accepts value in format "Y-m-d" (how is in @Eydun answer. Your used format is used in czech language, but date doesn't understand it. In your first try i would try to dump $date, if it realy contains string you specify there.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this:

```
    $form->addText('category_priority', 'Prioritizovať do')
    ->setType('date')
    ->setDefaultValue((new \DateTime)->format('Y-m-d'));
```